# Получить сумму столбца в связной таблице для каждой записи в Asp,net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Есть таблица должников и таблица их выплат по этому долгу, нужно вывести список должников и для каждой записи общую сумму выплат. Как это сделать при помощи EF, Linq ?

```
public class Debtor
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Кто")]
        public int person_id { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("person_id")]
        public Person person {get; set;}

        [Display(Name = "Сумма задолженности")]
        public double amount { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Кому должен")]
        public int project_id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("project_id")]
        public Project project { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Принятые меры")]
        public string actions { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Примечание")]
        public string note { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Payment> Payments { get; set; }

        public Debtor()
        {
            Payments = new List<Payment>();
        }
    }


public class Payment
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name ="Должник")]
        public int? Debtor_id { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Debtor_id")]
        public Debtor debtor { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name ="Сумма выплаты")]
        public double Pay_amount { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd'/'MM'/'yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Дата выплаты")]
        public DateTime Date  { get; set; }
    }
```

Пробовал так, но вылазит ошибка Элемент модели, переданный в словарь, имеет тип "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`1[System.Double]]", но для этого словаря требуется элемент модели типа "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Sb.Models.Debtor]".

```
 public ActionResult Index()
             {
                 SelectList persons = new SelectList(db.Persons, "Id", "FirstName");

        ViewBag.persons = persons;

        SelectList projects = new SelectList(db.Project, "Id", "Name");
        ViewBag.projects = projects;

        return View(db.Debtors
            .Include(p => p.person)
            .Include(p => p.project)
            .Include(p => p.Payments)
            .Select(g => new A { sum = g.Payments.Sum(x => x.Pay_amount) })
            .ToList()); }
```

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```
public class A
{
    public Debtor Debtor { get; set; }

    public Double Sum { get; set; }
}

db.Debtor
    .Include(p => p.Payments)
    .Select(y => new A {Debtor = y, Sum = y.Payments.Sum(x => x.Pay_amount)})
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Т.е нужно создавать ещё 1 класс? извиняйте за моё занудство, просто это меня немного напрягает, потому что php я выводил это обычным sql запросом

Comment: В C# тоже есть [анонимные типы](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types).