# Вывод количества городов для каждой страны Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Есть таблица стран и городов с кол-ом населения , нужно вывести Список стран и кол-во населения для каждой страны (сумма по колонке кол-ва для каждого города), делаю так в строго-типизированном представлении моделью

> `@model IEnumerable<Sb.Models.Country>`

выскакивает ошибка, что cписок должен быть IEnumerable, возможно ли вообще это вывести в строго тип-ом представлении и как иначе если нет, help please!

```
public class Country
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<City> Cities { get; set; }

    public Country()
    {
        Cities = new List<City>();
    }
}

public class A
{
    public Country country { get; set; }

    public Int quantity { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Country_id { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("Country_id")]
    public Country country { get; set; }

    public Int Quantity { get; set; }

}

public ActionResult Index()
        {

        var Countries = db.Country
            .Include(c => c.Cities)
            .Select(g => new A { Country = g, sum = g.Cities.Where(x => x.Country_id == g.Id).Sum(x => x.Quantity) }).ToList();

        return View(Countries);

    }
```

Ошибка 
     Элемент модели, переданный в словарь, имеет тип "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Sb.Models.A]", но для этого словаря требуется элемент модели типа "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Sb.Models.Country]".

Comment: Вы же [уже спрашивали](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/682151/213987) этот вопрос, зачем дублировать?

Comment: Подождите: `return View();` а где ваша модель? Вы делаете .ToArray() или .ToList()? И что во вью используется в `@model`? У вас там должно быть `IEnumerable<A>` или `A[]` или `List<A>`, а у вас что? Показывайте код, того что есть -- не хватает. И -- точный текст сообщения об ошибке не помешал бы.

Comment: Отредактировал пост

Comment: Вообще я хочу понять, если мне нужно вывести данные, которые образуются в результате определённых операций/выборки и тд, и не описаны ни в какой из таблиц / моделей, следует создавать дополнительный класс, где нужно описывать эти поля?

Comment: @ZxcR, ну так а чего вы ожидали, передавая во вьюшку `List<A>`, в то время как модель ожидает `IEnumerable<Country>` ? Передавайте во вью тот тип, который вы сами и определили.

Comment: @null, с этим разобрался исправил, всё заработало, меня лишь раздрожает, что нужно создавать новый класс, а если у меня по 10 таблиц, каждые из них связанны 1:M имею ввиду по парно(5/5) , то придётся создавать ещё 5 классов чтобы выводить информацию типа суммирования по колонке из связной таблицы?

Comment: @ZxcR, можете передавать оригиналы сущностей. То есть во вьюхе пишите как было "@model IEnumerable<Sb.Models.Country>", в контроллере "var Countries = db.Country.Include(c => c.Cities).ToList(); return View(Countries);" А отображать, например, так: "@foreach(var c in Model)Html.Raw(c.Cities.Sum(x => x.Quantity))"

Comment: @СергейПолушин, попробую, спасибо